# Checking parameters

Tags: c, parameters

I'm trying to check parameters when my program is started, but I have two problems and dont know how to solve them.

**1. Problem (SOLVED)**

When I run program: `./server -a SOMEADRESS -p` I got `Unauthorized access to memory (SIGSEGV)`. But if I run it with `-a SOMEADRESS -` or `-a SOMEADRESS fff` it prints righ error message from `else`.

**2. Problem**

I would like to get `address` and copy it into char array. But it lookl like nothing copy inside that array.

My check code:

```
int i = 0;
for(i = 1; i < argc; i++)
{
    if(strcmp("-h", argv[i]) == 0)
    {
        printf("Some help"0;
        exit(0);
    }
    else if(strcmp("-a", argv[i]) == 0)
    {
        if(argc > i)
        {
            if(strlen(argv[i + 1]) < 255)
            {
                //memset(adresa, '\0', sizeof(adresa));
                strcpy(argv[i + 1], adresa);
                printf("Zadana adresa %s\n", argv[i + 1]);

                i++;
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Adresa je prilis dlouha (> 255)\n");
                exit(0);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Parametry jsou ve spatnem tvaru\n");
        }
    }
    else if(strcmp("-p", argv[i]) == 0)
    {
        if(argc > i)
        {
            int inPort = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
            if(inPort > 0)
            {
                if(inPort <= 65535)
                {
                    port = inPort;
                    printf("Zadany port %d\n", port);

                    i++;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Zadany port neni ve spravnem rozsahu\n");
                    exit(0);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Zadany port neni cislo\n");
                exit(0);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Parametry jsou ve spatnem tvaru\n");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Parametry jsou ve spatnem tvaru\n");
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

It looks long, but it is because lot of `if`'s.

and error message:

```
sk1x1@sk1x1-VirtualBox:~/Plocha/tt$ ./server -a adress -p
4, 1
Zadana adresa 
4, 3
Neoprávněný přístup do paměti (SIGSEGV) (core dumped [obraz paměti uložen])
```

Comment: `printf("Some help"0;`??

Comment: The conventional prototype for `main()` is `int main(int argc, char** argv)`, not `int main(int argv, char **argc)`. Reversing this is gratuitously confusing to anyone who knows that a **c**ount and a **v**ector are not interchangeable.

Comment: @SouravGhosh
Just a typo in question, its long `printf` in my code

Comment: @EOF
I know, I have it in function, but I will rewrite it to the right conventional prototype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this check right after you see an option argument, `-a` or `-p`:

```
if(argc > i)
```

But that is true if argument `i` has been supplied, and you already know that: argument `i` was the `-p`. It does not verify that argument `i + 1` exists. So the above check is incorrect; it doesn't tell you anything about the following element in the argument vector. If there isn't one, you'll segfault when you try to use the argument.

You really should consider using [`getopt`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html). It does all this work for you.

Comment: Right, I rewrote it to `if(argc > (i + 1))`. Now it works, thanks! Do you also have some hint to second problem?

Comment: @Sk1X1: On SO, the rule is one post, one question. If you have a second question, ask a separate question. (But why do you want to copy the value? It is not going anywhere :-). ) Find more information about  `strcpy` with `man strcpy`

Comment: Okey, I will create new question. And it is because I need to use this value later in another function. So I want to check if value exists, copy it to another variable and the from variable use it.

Comment: @Sk1X1: You don't need to copy the string (unless you are planning on modifying it). You can just use the pointer as is. As I said, it's not going anywhere.

Comment: It mean just use `adresa = argv[i + 1]`?

Comment: @Sk1X1: If you declare `adresa` as `char*` (or `const char*`) instead of an array, yes, precisely what I meant. One of the many advantages (as well as simplicity) is that you don't have to worry about how long the string might be.

Comment: Okey, I will give it try when I will test my application later. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This will **always** be true

```
if (sizeof(argc[i + 1]) < 255)
```

the problem is that the `sizeof` operator does not compute the length of a string, for that you need `strlen()`, it gives the size of the argument instead, which in this case is a pointer. Also, normally the arguments are named `argv`, `argc` is the *argument count*.

Also, `memset()` there is absolutely unecessary just `strcpy()`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I edited my code and it looks like for cycle go to next iteration but still got the error. Error is now in my question